# can I know which CLI command is being executed in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to call a function only if a certain command is being used to start the flask app. I.e. I do not want to call the function if CLI command is 'initdb':

> flask initdb

but I want to call it when command is 'run':

> flask run --host=0.0.0.0

Is there a way of knowing what command flask was called with?

PS. I'm looking at flaskr code and trying to start a Process() only if flask is called with 'run'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. One way of solving this is by creating a environment variable.

When running the flask program you can assign a environment variable and then check if it's true or not.

```
SOME_VARIABLE=initdb flask run
```

then in the code definitions you would reference that variable as:

```
if os.environ['SOME_VARIABLE'] == 'initdb':
    ....
else:
    ....
```

You would not be able to use the word 'run' as the environment variable, but I think that would be frowned upon anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the contents of the `sys.argv` list after having created your flask application object (`app = Flask(__name__)`).

It should contain the command that was executed.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if sys.argv[1] == 'run':
   Process()
```